# Shell script - Log file not updating

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to get my shell script to alert me if the 2 log files is not updating. I am trying to get the current size... wait 10 seconds and if the file did not change size send an email alert. any help would be great!

My Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
logFiles="lg.log lg2.log"
logLocation="/user/file/logs"
sleepTime=10
subject="issue - file not updated"

failMessage="::no recent updates "
successMessage="OK"
not_updated_time=0
arr=($logFiles)
arrlen=${#arr[@]}
arrcount=()
date
for ((count=0; count<arrlen; count++)) ; do
    arrcount[$count]=`ls -l  $logLocation${arr[$count]}  |awk '{print $5}'`
    echo "${arr[$count]} Original size :: ${arrcount[$count]}"
done
echo
while [ "e" == "e" ] ; do
    sleep $sleepTime
    date
    for ((count=0; count<arrlen; count++)) ; do
        nc=`ls -l  $logLocation${arr[$count]}  |awk '{print $5}'`
        echo -n "${arr[$count]} "
        if [ $nc == ${arrcount[$count]} ] ; then
        echo 'error' | mailx -s "issue" cat@gmail.com
        else
            arrcount[$count]=$nc
            echo $successMessage
   not_updated_time=0
        fi
    done
    echo
done
```

Fixed the issue with comma, script still not working. any ideas?

Comment: `arr=($logFiles)` what is happening to the `comma`?

Comment: avoid using `ls -l` output if you can. Most systems have a `stat` process that can print any info you need for a filespec (single or multiples). Good luck.

Comment: what do you mean by that @David C. Rankin

Comment: Thanks, @shelter currently the script works in my environment but I can't figure out the email alert part of it if it does not update.

Comment: @connollyc4, on initial look at your script, you have `logFiles="lg.log, lg2.log"` which unless you have added the `comma` to `IFS` will result in your array contents being `lg.log,` and `lg2.log`. Note the `comma` at the end of `lg.log,`. For example, enter the following on the command line: `logFiles="lg.log, lg2.log"; arr=($logFiles); declare -p arr` Pay ***close*** attention to what your first array element holds.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a `/` missing either on the initialization of `logLocation` or when you're using that variable as `$logLocation${arr[$count]}`.

Try one of these two changes:

```
logLocation="/user/file/logs/"
```

Or:

```
`ls -l  $logLocation/${arr[$count]}  |awk '{print $5}'`
```

Comment: The script itself works. it's the email of the alert that doesn't. I'm trying to get the email alert part to work

Comment: Are the emails getting stuck on the server? Can you see them in the queue with `mailq`?